# How can I retrieve the class of an element using jQuery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, class

I have a bunch of inputs like this

```
<input id="someId" type="button" class="SomeClass" onclick="determineClass(this.id, event)" />
```

From javascript I would like to get the class, it's different for each input.

```
function determineClass(id, e) {
    var elementClass = //Somehow get the class here
}
```

It can be using jQuery or just plain javascript... Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
alert($('#someId').attr('class'));
```

If your input has multiple classes, `attr('class')` returns a space-delimited list of classnames. You can get the last one as follows:

```
alert($('#someId').attr('class').split(' ').slice(-1));
```

See [`Attributes/attr`](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/attr)

Answer (score 1):

[edit]

Ah crap... not what you meant...

$('#id').attr('class');

[/edit]

Comment: He is already using jQuery. There is no need to use another library.

Comment: You know you can delete an answer if it's not applicable to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You would use:

$('#someId').attr('class')

But beware that if it has multiple classes it will return a string of all of them, so you'll have to use indexOf or a regex to check for a specific class in that case.

Comment: Could also slide with $('#someId')[0].className.

Comment: ...or $('#someId:first').attr('class')

Comment: @David Andres - $('#someId:first') implies multiple elements of the same ID, big no-no.

Comment: @karim79: A big no-no, yes.  Not going to disagree on that point.

Answer (score 1):

A bit simpler using plain ol' JavaScript:

```
function determineClass(id, e)
{
  var elem = document.getElementById(id);

  if(elem)
  {
    alert(elem.className);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using plain ol' javascript, if you already have a variable/reference to the element, you can pull the class out using "element.className"

So, for your element "someId" above:

```
element = document.getElementById('someId');
if(element) elementClass = element.className
```

This gets a little more complicated if you have multiple classes assigned to the element -- you'd have to split what you find in the className property by a space in order to separate them -- but that's the basics.

That said, if you've got the chance, use jQuery. It generally makes this kind of thing easier.